# Compiled app wants to load DLL from absolute path

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, path

Hello to my little DLL hell!

I have written an application based on C++/Qt and it also uses [QCA](http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=qca.git) - the Qt Cryptographic Architecture. From there the basic stuff is available via `libqca.dll`, more stuff like decryption is provided by separate plugins. QCA is compiled via cmake, make, make install.
It installes the DLLs and a mkspec feature in the Qt installation directory.

After compiling QCA and then my application, it ran fine. But when I installed this app on another computer without any development stuff, the additional `libqca-ossl.dll` providing AES decryption was not loaded during runtime.

Dependency Walker revealed, that my app is trying to load the latter DLL from here:

```
C:/Qt/4.8.4/plugins/crypto/libqca-ossl.dll
```

This is the path, where it was installed on the development computer. Clearly, this path doesn't exist on other computers. When I created this path on that other machine and put the DLL inside, it is loaded.
Both DLLs, that are needed, already reside in the EXE's directory and should be found there.

So it seems to me, the DLLs absolute install path got somehow hardcoded into the application. 
How can I make my app find the DLL, that's sitting next to the EXE?

Comment: how did you compile the lib for this dll on your exe?

Comment: Given the short compilation procedure above, I am not sure I am following you. Could you state more precisely, what kind of information you need, please?

Comment: @AndreasN, please provide relevant excerpt form your .pro file

Comment: For completeness: I just say `win32:CONFIG += crypto` in my .pro file. This includes the crypto.prf from the QTDIR/mkspecs/features path. Its content is in the file crypto.prf.in (last 10 lines) from the KDE git repository (see link in my inital post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "How does it work?" on the [QCA project home page](http://delta.affinix.com/qca/):

> Crypto functionality is determined during runtime, and plugins are loaded from the ‘crypto’ subfolder of the Qt Library Paths.

So the behaviour you describe is as-expected.

To make it work, you will need to either change the Qt library paths folder at runtime, or explicitly insert the provider you want using [`QCA::InsertProvider`](http://delta.affinix.com/docs/qca/namespaceQCA.html#62a0e1e519e664e2db003c14715f1125), as [described in the documentation](http://delta.affinix.com/docs/qca/providers.html).  The latter is probably preferable as it is more localized.  Changing the library paths might conceivably introduce side-effects into the rest of your application, or conflict with other third-party libraries.

Comment: I accept this answer, because it helped me nail the problem. Apparently, I have overlooked some important stuff of the documentation. 

The citation about the 'crypto' subfolder turned on a light. As the EXE path is in `QApplication::libraryPaths()`, it is sufficient to copy the 'crypto' subfolder along with its libqca-ossl.dll into the EXE path of the application. 
It should be noted, that the libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from an OpenSSL installation are also required in the EXE path.

Thank you all.